# What do you call a garment that is like a hoodie but has a zipper and doesn't have a hood?

Tags: single-word-requests

Hoodie has a hood, sweater is knitted or crocheted, pullover, jumper and sweatshirt seem to all be related but neither has a zipper, zip-up does but at least in the pictures they all seem to have hoods too and jacket is for outdoors. What do you call a garment that is like a hoodie but has a zipper and doesn't have a hood?

And yes, I realize there are differences between different variants of English but if I wanted to reference them all, this would be a book (English seems to have a ridiculous number of names for garments that are all similar).

Also, is there a universal name for all/most of the above so I don't have to wonder about the details every time I want to mention one?

Comment: What kind of fabric? Jersey like a sweatshirt? Knit like a sweater? Nylon like a windbreaker?

Comment: Does the zipper go all the way or is it just a “quarter zip”?

Comment: Do an image search on google with words you think are related - it might have a picture of what you're thinking. Then post a picture here of that

Comment: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-a-hoodie-without-a-hood-called) suggests "bunnyhug". No evidence, but nice if true. (They also have boring things like full-zip sweatshirt).

Answer (score 6):

I'd call it a *cardigan*, or perhaps a *zip-up cardigan* if I wanted to be specific.

From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cardigan):

> **cardigan** n.
> A knitted garment, such as a sweater or jacket, that opens down the full length of the front.

If it's not actually knitted, then I'd go ahead and call it a *jacket*. (Note that knitted fabric still counts as knitted. Most t-shirts and hoodies are made of knitted fabric.)

[Same source](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jacket):

> **jacket** n.
>
> 1. A short coat usually extending to the hips.

Comment: If this isn't the answer I'll eat my cardigan, which I won't have to do because it will be called something else.

Comment: cardigans rarely have zippers, they have buttons, usually. Though zip-up cardigan would work.

Answer (score 1):

Sweatshirt.  Most of mine have had zippers.

[Here are some samples](https://www.zappos.com/zipper-sweatshirts).

Comment: Most of mine have had hoods.

Comment: I think you need the qualifier zipper or zip-up. Statistically the majority of sweatshirts don't have zips.

Comment: @StuartF  Do you have statistics on that?

Answer (score -1):

The British and US terms for this are different . [The Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/windcheater) gives "windcheater" (Br) and "windbreaker" (US),

I had thought that "windcheater" was a bit dated because I haven't heard it in normal.use for some time but searching for it online returns a large number of current advertising entries so the garment industry must still use it even if the general publuc don't.

If the garment is made of polyester pile fleece, however, it's usually called a "fleece".

A few of the advertising entries for "windcheater" do show garments with hoods but they all seem to have full-length zips so I believe "windcheater" or "windbreaker" to be the best word for a hoodless hoodie with a full.length zip.

Comment: A windcheater is windproof (hence the name), so it's likely to be a top-layer outdoor garment. The question implies a different garment, I think.

Comment: @AndrewLeach For me a **hoodie** is  normally worn as a top garment.

Comment: Like Andrew said, the main defining feature of a windbreaker/cheater is the first part of the name: **wind**. A hoodie, cardigan, or sweater are worth shit-all against the wind, so would never be described as a windbreaker.

Comment: Yeah a windcheater or windbreaker has a very close weave. James Dean's jacket in Rebel Without A Cause is an iconic example. In contrast a sweatshirt is knitted jersey cotton or poly-cotton.